# Extracting files from powershell which don't have '.zip' extension

Tags: powershell

I have files inside the folder which do not have extensions like **'.zip'**:

[image]

The file is seen as File in the folder.

```
$zipfile = "\\ccaintranet.com\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\FTP-FromClient\OracleRMS\Extraction\2022-04-30\CONNOLLY_20220429191553"
$tmp = "\\ccaintranet.com\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\FTP-FromClient\OracleRMS\Extraction\2022-04-30\"

# Extract the 'extract.txt' file to your temp folder
Expand-Archive -Path $zipfile -DestinationPath $tmp -Force
```

I searched this answer in powershell but it says the error as:

```
Expand-Archive : is not a supported archive file format. .zip is the only supported archive file format.
```

How can I extract these files using powershell?

Comment: Using `Expand-Archive` to extract a ZIP file without file extension works for me with PS 5.1. Which version of PowerShell are you using (type `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`)? Also, are you sure that what you have actually is a ZIP file? Try `Format-Hex $zipfile` - does it start with the letters `PK` (bytes `50` `4B`)?

Comment: It's saying Major 5 and Minor as 1 Revision as 5066 and Build 14393

Comment: Mine is build 19041, so this might indeed be something that has been fixed in a newer PS version. Does it work when you copy the ZIP to a local folder and append `.zip` extension?

Comment: not its not working even when i renamed the file to .zip. It says end of central directory record could not be found

Comment: It looks like the ZIP file is either damaged or it uses a format not supported by `Expand-Archive`. Can you extract it using 7-zip?

Comment: obviously renaming doesn't help because no one looks at the extension for determining the type, they only check the magic number which is "PK" for zip files and you have to use `Format-Hex` to check it as mentioned above